# NodeJS + Python Scripts (using numpy, scipy, etc) on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, numpy, heroku, scipy

I want to take advantage of NodeJS's **streaming** and **async** functionalities (and it's super easy to use), as well as Python's **numerical computing** libraries like **numpy** and **scipy**.

Basically, all I want to do is call a **Python script** from NodeJS. I believe I can use the npm module python-shell to do this.

But how does this work when I deploy to Heroku? My package.json only includes my node related dependencies, like express.

Where do I specify my Python dependencies (numpy, scipy, etc) (the requirements.txt file) within my node project, or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: I also want to use python and numpy in node.js. But I don't know how to import numpy.
Did you solve your question? Can you tell me how to solve it?